# Issues with new Version of CycloneDX for dotnet in azuredevops context

Tags: azure-devops

With the new release of the cyclonedx dotnet tool, our automated generation of SBOM don't work anymore.

With the version 2.3.0, all was fine.
With version 2.4.1 (the latest), the tool shows warning when scanning dotnet/corefx :

...
Retrieving GitHub license for repository dotnet/corefx and ref master
GitHub API failed with status code NotFound and message Not Found.
No license found on GitHub for repository dotnet/corefx using ref master
Retrieving GitHub license for repository dotnet/corefx and ref master
GitHub API failed with status code NotFound and message Not Found.
...

And after that it raises the following exception :

Unhandled exception. System.IO.InvalidDataException: Central Directory corrupt.
---> System.IO.IOException: An attempt was made to move the position before the beginning of the stream.
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin loc)
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()
at System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)
at CycloneDX.Services.NugetV3Service.GetNuspec(String name, String version, String nuspecFilename, FindPackageByIdResource resource) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Services/NugetV3Service.cs:line 315
at CycloneDX.Services.NugetV3Service.GetNuspec(String name, String version, String nuspecFilename, FindPackageByIdResource resource) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Services/NugetV3Service.cs:line 315
at CycloneDX.Services.NugetV3Service.GetComponentAsync(String name, String version, Nullable`1 scope) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Services/NugetV3Service.cs:line 231
at CycloneDX.Services.NugetV3Service.GetComponentAsync(NugetPackage nugetPackage) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Services/NugetV3Service.cs:line 322
at CycloneDX.Program.OnExecuteAsync(CommandLineApplication app) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Program.cs:line 281
at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.InvokeAsync(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] arguments)
at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.OnExecute(ConventionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Conventions.ExecuteMethodConvention.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync[TApp](CommandLineContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at CycloneDX.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/runner/work/cyclonedx-dotnet/cyclonedx-dotnet/CycloneDX/Program.cs:line 130
at CycloneDX.Program.(String[] args)

Does anyone has encountered this issue in azure devops or other tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me, when running via docker and on version 2.7.0

The solution was to allow package restore (don't `--disable-package-restore`) and give the `--url` parameter, pointing to our internal nuget repository.

my call now looks like

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/app" -w /app \
    cyclonedx/cyclonedx-dotnet \
    --json -f /app/service.bom.json -o /app \
    --exclude-test-projects \
    --exclude-dev \
    -gt token -gu user \ 
    --url https://nuget-repo-url/index.json
    ./service.sln
```